# Formatting Title element in XML Feed with HTML tags

Tags: asp.net, feed, syndicationfeed

I am using ASP.Net's inbuilt classes to create XML feeds for a website. Here's the code I have,

```
SyndicationFeed myFeed = new SyndicationFeed();
myFeed.Title = TextSyndicationContent.CreatePlaintextContent
("XYZ  - In the first line &lt;br/&gt; in the second line");
```

When rendered it shows as it is -

```
XYZ  - In the first line &lt;br/&gt; in the second line
```

whereas I want it

```
XYZ  - In the first line 
in the second line
```

I see that the behavior is only to myFeed.Title, whereas in myFeed.Description, I can use any HTML tags.

Any way to get HTML tags working with Titles?

Comment: if this is the actual case you use html decode or if you can make the change in xml file you can keep the data in CDATA block.

Comment: tried both, but doesn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SyndicationContent.CreateHtmlContent Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationcontent.createhtmlcontent%28v=vs.100%29) instead. SyndicationContent.CreatePlaintextContent always escapes the text to make it render literally.

Comment: I tried this option, but the HTML tags are not getting applied.

Comment: If you look at the raw feed content does the tag show correctly in there? This may be a client rendering issue.

Comment: Yes, the feed content appears correctly in the source. May be its a client issue, but it doesn't work as desired in either IE8/9 or Mozilla 14. I need to get them working at least in IE.